# Bootstrap 4 card going out of bounds due to a large image

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to place a card within a vertical swiper. The vertical swiper consists of many such bootstrap cards.

When the image of the card is long enough, it gets only partially displayed and does not adjust itself to the size of its parent element.

JSFiddle displaying the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/kxsnbw3h/6/

Can the card's image be made responsive to always be contained in the space available?

```js
var vswiper = new Swiper('.v-swiper-container', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  speed: 2000,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 2000,
  },
  loop: true,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
});
```

```css
.mh-50 {
  max-height: 50vh;
}

.clip {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.6/js/swiper.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.6/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 mh-50 clip">
      <div class="v-swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">

          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/1500x200?text=Week-1" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">Week 1</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Week 1 text.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Week 1 button</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/900x500?text=Week-2" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">Week 2</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Week 2 text.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Week 2 button</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 mh-50">
      <img src="//placehold.it/200x100?text=Col-2" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="//placehold.it/500x100?text=Row-2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .img-responsive is .img-fluid in Bootstrap4. I've applied that.